# iOS PushKit (VoIP Push Notifications) Quality of Service

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

What is the PushKit QoS policy? The [policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4) for the regular push notification is defined as store-and-forward.

> Apple Push Notification service includes a default Quality of Service
>   (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline,
>   the notification is stored for a limited period of time, and delivered
>   to the device when it becomes available.
>
> Only one recent notification for a particular app is stored. If
>   multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new
>   notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This
>   behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as
>   coalescing notifications.
>
> If the device remains offline for a long time, any notifications that
>   were being stored for it are discarded.

What about PushKit notification? Is it the same as for regular push notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I performed the following steps to verify the issue myself

1. Put the device in airplane mode
2. Sent at least 5 different PushKit notifications
3. Wait for about 3 minutes
4. Cancel the airplane mode

Only the last PushKit notification arrived which is compatible with the [store-and-forward](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4) Apple's policy (which is specifically defined for regular remote push notifications).